# order of dependencies in make

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

Since it is said that order of dependencies does matter in a makefile. I wish to understand how:

```
finalObjectFile: x.o main.o y.o
    g++ x.o main.o y.o -o finalObjectFile

main.o: header/x.h source/main.cpp
    g++ -c source/main.cpp

x.o: header/x.h source/x.cpp
    g++ -c source/x.cpp

y.o: source/y.cpp header/x.h
    g++ -c source/y.cpp
```

In the above code I have swapped the positions of the header file x.h:

```
x.o: header/x.h source/x.cpp
        g++ -c source/x.cpp

y.o: source/y.cpp header/x.h
        g++ -c source/y.cpp
```

but the output doesn't get effected!

Which kind of dependencies are ACTUALLY important to be in order?

Comment: Where did you hear this? I never ran into any issue with it...

Comment: @EricJohnson See this: http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/Make/3-3.html

Comment: The terminology in the referenced page is wrong.  It was written in 2001; it should have been removed from the web in 2001 too.  Or fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context shown, there is no significant difference between *header before source* and *source before header*.  The rules say (for example):

- `x.o` must be more recent than `header/x.h` and `source/x.cpp`.

It doesn't matter which sequence those two dependencies appear in; if either dependency is newer than `x.o`, the command will be executed.

When does the order matter?  That's a bit trickier to exemplify, but might be a factor if you have multiple intermediate files that get generated as you go.  It might especially be a problem if some of the commands you execute affect multiple files but you don't properly tell `make` about all those interactions.

However, dependency order normally isn't a problem.

Comment: See this: http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/Make/3-3.html `The order in which dependencies are listed is important. `

Comment: That's a piece of tripe, Anisha - sorry, but it is appallingly bad.  It is referring to targets, not dependencies.  The order in which the targets appear in the makefile is marginally important; it matters because the first target in the makefile is the one that will be made when you type `make` without specifying which target you want.  Conventionally, the first target is `all`.  You can build any desired target by specifying it on the command line: `make target1 target2` etc.  But targets are not dependencies.  So, forget what that manual said - it said it all wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment Jon, so the outcome is that the order of dependencies does NOT matter in any way? I have a question about targets too, BTW>

Comment: Order of dependencies is almost never a problem; I don't recall any circumstances when I've run into an issue, except when `make` was not told the whole truth about something.  Is your question about targets a separate question on SO, or are you planning to augment this one with the extra request?

Comment: Thanks again Jon, I think making a new question on targets will be more appropriate. :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Which prerequisite is first in the list is normally significant, because it is the one which will be used with `$<`.  In real life, people don't write the same rule dozens of times.  They define a macro along the lines of `compile = g++ -c $< -o $@`, and invoke it.  So that if they want to add an option (`-ggdb`, anyone?), they only have to add it in one place.

Comment: That depends on whether you're discussing `make` or GNU Make.  [POSIX `make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) and other non-GNU versions of `make` do not take `$<` as the first prerequisite.  I see that the question does have a 'gnumake' tag.  I agree 100% that all the compilation lines need to be macroized.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've been using GNU make for so long that I'd forgotten about the others.  I should have said that it was GNU specific.

Answer (score 2):

It matters in real make files, because you tend to use packaged rules. 
In a rule, `$<` is replaced by the **first** prerequisite.  Thus:

```
compile = g++ -c $< -o $@

x.o : source/x.cpp header/x.h
    $(compile)

y.o : header/y.h source/y.cpp
    $(compile)
```

The first rule will compile `source/x.cpp`, as desired.  The second rule
will attempt to compile `header/y.h`, which is definitely not what is
wanted.

Since this is a far more typical (and rational) way of writing
makefiles, you do have to respect order, at least with regards to which
element comes first.

Another case it might matter (but which shouldn't be the case in a well
written makefile): in many cases, `make` will resolve the dependencies
in a left to right order; i.e. given:

```
x.o : source/x.cpp header/x1.h header/x2.h
    ...
```

`make` will first check that `source/x.cpp` is up to date, and build it
if necessary, and then do the same for `header/x1.h` and `header/x2.h`,
in that order.  If you have any non-stated dependencies, which require
`header/x1.h` to be built before `header/x2.h`, then changing their
order will also cause problems.  This is, however, an error in the
makefile; the dependency should be made explicit (e.g. a rule with
`header/x1.h : header/x2.h`).  Because this order is not guaranteed
otherwise; in the case of GNU make, for example, it may be violated if
you use the `-j` option.
`header/x.h`, then swapping the order may cause problems.

Comment: The second half of your answer seems a bit unneeded. Not incorrect, but I don't think it necessary to discuss the situation of a faulty makefile. The matter of the automatic variable `$<` was the first thing that popped into my head, as well, although your mention of packaged rules is a bit superfluous. Automatic variables may just as well be used directly in a recipe.

Comment: @eriktous I was basically trying to explain a case where he might see an apparent dependency on order.  I agree that the correct way to handle this is to fix the makefile.  With regards to packaged rules: it's true that automatic variables can be used in any rule, but there's really no need to except in packaged rules.